# jquery horizontal submenu stay open on menu click

Tags: jquery, html, css, submenu

Maybe this is a related question, but I couldn't find a good solution for it, so here is my question.
I have a horizontal menu with some subitems. At the moment when I click on the main menu the submenu is being shown and it remains open even if I click anywhere on the page.
But here is the tricky part, when I click on a menu item (in the submenu) I want the submenu to display the items on which the page is.
For example the menu looks like this: home, page1, page2 and submenu (of page1): page1a, page1b. So when I click on page1, submenu with page1a and page1b opens, but when I click on page1a the page for page1a opens but the submenu remains closed, while I want it to display the submenu of page1.
Here is the html menu I have:

```
<ul id="topnav">
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Over Meves</a>
        <!--Submenu begint hier-->
        <span>
            <a href="#">Historie</a> |
            <a href="#">Onze mensen</a> |
            <a href="#">Werkzijze</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Disciplines</a>
        <!--Submenu begint hier-->
        <span>
            <a href="vervolg.html">Klimaatbeheersing</a> |
            <a href="#">Elektrotechniek</a> |
            <a href="#">Sanitaire techniek</a> |
            <a href="#">Energiebesparingstechniek</a> |
            <a href="#">Bouwfysica en geluid</a> |
            <a href="#">Diensten energiebesparing</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Expertise</a>
        <!--Submenu begint hier-->
        <span>
            <a href="#">Woningbouw & Utiliteit</a> |
            <a href="#">Zorg & Welzijn</a> |
            <a href="#">Milieu & Energie</a> |
            <a href="#">Beheer & Onderhoud</a> |
            <a href="#">EPA & EPC</a> |
            <a href="#">Legionella beheersing</a>
        </span>             
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <!--Submenu begint hier-->
        <span>
            <a href="#">Adres & route</a> |
            <a href="#">Werken bij</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The jquery that opens the submenu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ddmenuitem = 0;
function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_close();
ddmenuitem = $(this).find('span').css('display', 'block');
}
function jsddm_close()
{  
if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('display', 'none');
}
$(document).ready(function()
{  
$('#topnav > li').bind('click', jsddm_open)
$('#topnav > li > a').click(function(){
if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
$('#topnav li a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
}
});
$('.project-tekst').trimTxt();
});
</script>
```

And the css for the menu:

```
ul#topnav 
{
float: left;
width: 900px;
background: #00537F;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
margin-top: 3px;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
font-size: 12px;
}
ul#topnav li 
{
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul#topnav li a
{
padding: 5px 15px;
color: #00537F;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
}
ul#topnav li a:link
{
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
ul#topnav li a:visited
{
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
ul#topnav li a:hover
{
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: underline;
}
ul#topnav li a.active
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #FFF;
}
ul#topnav li span 
{
float: left;
padding: 4px 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 24px;
display: none;
background: #e0e0e0;
color: #00537F;
}
ul#topnav li span a
{
display: inline;
color: #00537F;
padding: 4px 8px;
}
ul#topnav li span a:link
{
color: #00537F;
}
ul#topnav li span a:visited
{
color: #00537F;
}
ul#topnav li span a:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #00537F;
}
ul#topnav li span a.active
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #00537F;
}
```

I hope you guys can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: I have add the code to jsfiddle.net: [http://jsfiddle.net/ud2011/QQQdH/4/]. As you can see the onclick works even when clicking on a different menu item, but this only works when the href is not set (just the #). Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: No one who can help me??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem.

Here what I did in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QQQdH/765/

First I added the current class on the Disciplines menu (like if I was on the Discipline page).

```
 <a href="http://google.com/" class="current">Disciplines</a>
```

Second, inside the click listener, I stop the propagation (going to the href) when the  has current.

```
   $('#topnav > ul > li > a').click(function(ev){
    if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
```

So with this menu, I can see the submenu even if there is a href="something".